# C# Parameter is reset sometimes when passed to a method running inside a task

Tags: c#, .net

For reference, I'm using .net 4.6.2.

I have a private method that does a calculation and adds the result of that calculation to a ConcurrentBag.

```
private void doSomething(List<myClass> list, ConcurrentBag<resClass> cb)
{
 // do calcs over items in list
 cb.Add(res);
}
```

Outside, I'm calling it like this:

```
    ConcurrentBag<resClass> cb = new ConcurrentBag<resClass>();
        List<Task> bagAddTasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach(var item in myList)
        {
           List<myClass> myClassList = new List<myClass>() { item };
           bagAddTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => doSomething(myClassList, cb));
        }
        
        // Consume the items in the bag
Task.WaitAll(bagAddTasks.ToArray());
        List<Task> bagConsumeTasks = new List<Task>();
        int itemsInBag = 0;
        while (!cb.IsEmpty)
        {
            bagConsumeTasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                resClass x;
                if (cb.TryTake(out x))
                {
                    resClassList.Add(x);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref itemsInBag);
                }
            }));
        }
    Task.WaitAll(bagConsumeTasks.ToArray());
```

Sometimes the item in the parameter 'list' being passed to 'doSomething' is reset, like if a new instance was created, thus all its properties are null.

Can someone help me figure out why this is happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: "thus all its properties are null." - how does this manifest? Is the code throwing null reference exceptions?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, properties which were filled before passing the list to the method are being used in the calculation method and throw a null reference exception. When looking at the class, all it's properties are now null.

Comment: You almost certainly have some type of threading bug. I.e. some object is being modified at the same time it is read, without the proper synchronization. But your example seem to have redacted any such code. If you want to make sure to avoid such problems, use immutable objects and collections.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least one race condition, there is no guarantee `while (!cb.IsEmpty)` is ever entered. It will take some time for `doSomething` to start adding items, and even it it has started, there is no guarantee you will run `bagConsumeTasks.Add` once for each item in `cb`. Could be more, could be less, but it is probably not correct.

This can cause problems down the line with some other component starting to modify some object that is unintentionally shared between threads.

I'm not sure what bagConsumeTasks  is supposed to do, if you want to ensure you are waiting for all tasks to complete, just run `Task.WaitAll(bagAddTasks)`. Whenever you are using the concurrent collections you need to ensure you do not have dependencies between multiple calls, since the collection may change. That is the reason for methods like `TryTake`, it both checks if there are items, and returns them, in a single, thread safe call.

I would highly recommend using higher level primitives for whatever you intend to do, like [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-7.0) or [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), this should make simple mistakes like this a little bit harder.

Comment: You're right about Task.WaitAll. When I was redacting my original code, I forgot to add it to my post. I'm reviewing my code and will come back with what I find.